# Objective-c coding conventions

Tags: objective-c, coding-style, objective-c++, conventions

I'm seeking for best practices and coding conventions, so have a question on this.
Looked trough almost all of them, but couldn't find any answers.
Example function:

```
- (int)getSomeNumber
{
    int result = 0;
    if (something) {
       result++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Question is, is it better to write result++, or ++result.
If someone knows some suggestions or answers why is it better to write in one way or the other it would be very great. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter the slightest when used as a statement (note that it *does* matter when part of a larger expression), as long as you are consistent. Don't mix styles within one source file or project.

Well, even better in this specific example would be `return something ? 1 : 0;`. Some people even prefer `return something;`, but I don't because in my eyes it makes no sense to convert a Boolean into an integer.

Comment: thanks for your answer :) Also thought something similar, but as I'm still quite new, am trying to make the best of it. Good luck